# Regarding drop in stamina while running?

Tags: running, jogging

I started running after I discover I am putting a lot of weight.When I started running my distance keep on increasing from 2.5 km to 5.0 km.But from few days I am unable to complete even 2.5 km.There is the pain in calf muscles and what I do is jog continuously and when there is a break in momentum I stop.So, my question is why there is a drop in stamina?
I have a 400 m track near my locality and i started with 5 rounds and gradually increasing with half round per day and i have  arest day on sunday.
It was like 
day 1:5 rounds
day 2:5.5 rounds
day 3:6 rounds
day 4 :off
day 5:6.5 rounds
going on and on day appart from sunday i had a day off.

I am new here if I didn't follow the question guidelines so please ignore.

Comment: Can you update question to include if you have rest days?  Maybe include a specific schedule - day 1: 2.5km, day 2: 3km, day 3: rest, day 4: 4km, day 5: rest.

Comment: just updated my answer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to let your body rest/repair a little more.  Eat some protein after a run and have a rest day in between.  Try it out for a week or two...  This was supposed to be a comment and I don't know how to delete. Sorry!